# Importing cells from Excel to Word as the replies of the comments

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to import cells form excel to word as the replies of the comments (children to the original comments)

I exported comments from .docx file to .xls with these attributes:

```
oComment.Index
oComment.Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
oComment.Initial,
oComment.Author,
oComment.Date,
oComment.Range
```

I added the replies to these comments in the new cell in excell. Now I want to import these replies into Word again, but as the replies of these original comments. I quess it will be posibble, beacuse the index of the original comments is the same. Can you help me with this issue :)? I can't code in VBA and I haven't found the answer of this question in the internet.

PS. I need also information, which library should I add if I need it.

This is macro which I used for exporting comments from word to excell:

```
Sub Export_Comments()

    ' Purpose: Search for comments in any text that's been p
    ' this document, then export them into a new Excel spreadsheet.
    ' Requires reference to Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library in VBA,
    ' which should already be saved with as part of the structure of
    ' this .docm file.

    Dim bResponse As Integer

    ' Exit routine if no comments have been found.
    If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count = 0 Then
      MsgBox ("No comments found in this document")
      Exit Sub
    Else
      bResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to export all comments to an Excel worksheet?", _
                  vbYesNo, "Confirm Comment Export")
      If bResponse = 7 Then Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create a object to hold the contents of the
    ' current document and its text. (Shorthand
    ' for the ActiveDocument object.
    Dim wDoc As Document
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument

    ' Create objects to help open Excel and create
    ' a new workbook behind the scenes.
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oComment As Comment         'Comment object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

    ' Create a new Workbook. Shouldn't interfere with
    ' other Workbooks that are already open. Will have
    ' at least one worksheet by default.
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    With xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

      ' Create headers for the comment information
      .Offset(0, 0) = "Comment Number"
      .Offset(0, 1) = "Page Number"
      .Offset(0, 2) = "Reviewer Initials"
      .Offset(0, 3) = "Reviewer Name"
      .Offset(0, 4) = "Date Written"
      .Offset(0, 5) = "Comment Text"

      ' Export the actual comments information
      For i = 1 To wDoc.Comments.Count
       Set oComment = wDoc.Comments(i)
       Set rngaComment = oComment.Reference
       rngaComment.Select
       Set rngHeading = wDoc.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range
       rngHeading.Collapse wdCollapseStart
       Set rngHeading = rngHeading.Paragraphs(1).Range
      .Offset(i, 0) = oComment.Index
      .Offset(i, 1) = oComment.Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
      .Offset(i, 2) = oComment.Initial
      .Offset(i, 3) = oComment.Author
      .Offset(i, 4) = Format(oComment.Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
      .Offset(i, 5) = oComment.Range
      .Offset(i, 6) = rngHeading.ListFormat.ListString & " " & rngHeading.Text
      .Offset(i, 7) = Format(oComment.Date, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Next i
    End With

    ' Make the Excel workbook visible
    xlApp.Visible = True

    ' Clean up our objects
    Set oComment = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, you need use the macro that you provided and then save the excel file that the macro made.

Then let's say you added the replies to the comments in the column "I"

[image]

Then copy the below code to your main Word document and run it.
It is going to open the Excel file (don't forget to change the path in the code!), loop through all rows, take the index of the comment and your reply, search this comment in the Word file and add new reply to it.
If you let one of the values in I column empty, macro will skip it and go to next row.

```
Sub Reply()
Dim excel As excel.Application
Dim wb    As Workbook
Dim ws    As Worksheet

Set excel = New excel.Application
'change this path to the path of excel file with extracted comments
Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Kirszu\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
excel.Visible = True

Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Dim comments As Variant
Dim com      As Variant
Set comments = doc.comments()

Dim i        As Long
Dim lastRow  As Long
Dim index As Long
Dim count As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    index = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    comReply = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
    For Each com In comments
        If com.index() = index + count Then
            Set repl = com.replies()
            If comReply <> "" Then
                repl.Add Range:=com.Range, _
                Text:=comReply
                count = count + 1
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next com
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope it's going to work! If something is confusing or needs more clarification, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: Hi! This is exactly what i wanted :)! Thank you very much!